# can I execute two methods on a one-liner foreach loop?

Tags: java, methods, foreach

I think the title is self explanatory. I need to execute two different methods inside a foreach loop method. For example, I currently have
`Files.walk(pathToHeaven).filter(Files::isRegularFile).forEach((path) -> doSomething(var1, path));`

could I modify this line to execute a second method after the `doSomething()`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure, just add curly brackets:

```
Files.walk(pathToHeaven).filter(Files::isRegularFile).forEach((path) -> { 
        doSomething(var1, path); 
        System.out.println("Hi there");
    }
);
```

The above is in accordance to the syntax of [Lambda Expressions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/lambda-1984522.html):

> The syntax of a lambda expression is as follows.
>
> (formal parameter list) ->{ expression or statements }

Comment: lol.. that was simple. Was trying to get it by just adding semicolon in between. Close enough :p

Comment: The concept of lambda exp. really  makes developers life easier. we can minimize line of code by which code readability is increased.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, possible.

Simply enclose your statement in curly brackets, as such:

```
Files
    .walk(pathToHeaven)
    .filter(Files::isRegularFile)
    .forEach(
        (path) -> {
            doSomething(var1, path);
            doSomethingElse(var2, path);
        }
);
```